# Postfix custom log

Tags: postfix, logging, email

Is there any way to customize postfix logging? I'm trying to get some reports out of it and I find it almost impossible to parse on it's default. Probably a XML like logging would be perfect.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered [logwatch](http://sourceforge.net/projects/logwatch/), which is usually the default log digest packaged with several linux installs?

Answer (score 0):

I know there are some log analyzer.
Check if one of those can help you:

http://www.postfix.org/addon.html#logfile

Answer (score 0):

You can't configure logging formats directly from postfix.  You'd have to parse the syslog formatted stuff and create your format, at which point it would be easier to just use the syslog stuff.