# Logging received from timestamp in postfix

Tags: postfix, logging

For incoming emails to a postfix server, i would like to record the timestamp in the "Receive: from" header.

For example, from an email containing:

```
Received: from mailserver01 ([192.168.0.25]) by mailserver01.domain.intra with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.5);
 Mon, 16 Jul 2012 17:09:36 +0200
```

I would like to extract:

```
Mon, 16 Jul 2012 17:09:36 +0200
```

What i would like to know is how to configure postfix to log that information (just the timezone or the whole "Received: from" header). I can handle the parsing to extract the information once i have that line logged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any config option to customize the log format. Have you tried running `postconf` to see if there's any option that deals with the log format?

Anyway, a similar question has been asked before, and it seems that it's not possible

[Postfix custom log](https://serverfault.com/questions/160347/postfix-custom-log)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it to **cut**

```
echo "Received: from mailserver01 ([192.168.0.25]) by mailserver01.domain.intra with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.5);      Mon, 16 Jul 2012 17:09:36 +0200" | cut -d ";" -f 2
```

or if you place email content in bash variable:

```
cat $email | grep "Received:" | cut -d ";" -f 2
```

Comment: I dont need to do the parsing, what i need to do is the logging. But thanks anyway!